# Is it possible to change tab/focus order in an HTML table so that it transfers vertically first and then horizontally?

Tags: html, tabs, html-table, focus

Is it possible to change tab/focus order in an HTML table so that it transfers vertically first and then horizontally?

Comment: What do you mean with "transfer"? The server will always transfer the html file from the beginning, regardless of its content.

Comment: The thing is about pressing a tab key on Input elements.

Comment: then your question shall point out clearer what transfer means in this case. Hitting the tab key in completely unrelated to transferring stuff!

Comment: Oh come on. It's understandable, unless you're stuck on a single technical definition of "transfer". Not everybody's a native English speaker.

Comment: @tuergeist reading the OP it does state "tab/focus in an html table" and the tags used to categorize the question include "html" & "table", if that's not enough information for you to establish a context about what he is asking then you are not qualified to be answering questions on SO. Further more, if the implied context has escaped you even when given plenty of information to establish the correct context I would have to question your ability to build software in this day and age where one is most always challenged with making assumptions when requirements are not always clear to everyone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suppose you have some kind of input elements in your table and on those you can set the tabindex attribute.

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
  <TD><INPUT NAME="Name" TABINDEX=1></TD>
  <TD><INPUT NAME="Age" TABINDEX=3></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD><INPUT NAME="Sex" TABINDEX=2></TD>
  <TD><INPUT NAME="Location" TABINDEX=4></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [`tabindex` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex).

Comment: +1. You'll also have to know/guess how many controls come before the table in the render order (e.g. a login form at the top of the page), and how many rows are going to be in the table (e.g. page size).